# Why cannot I approve suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I still remember the time as I was able to approve suggested edits. Then at some point my approvals start require an agreement of a further user.

The only possible reason for this restriction I can imagine: once I approved a good edit but to the moment of the approval some other user has edited the post and the edit which I have approved (and which suggested essentially the same changes) was undone.

But this is only a suggestion which I would like now to resolve. Therefore my question: what is the exact reason for this restriction and when will it end?

Comment: When you vote on a suggested edit, after someone else has, as well, and your votes agree, then it appears to one that they alone approved the edit. (Also, any third voter an a review which had two opposing votes accept/decline, then as the third vote, you are the tie breaker.  But unless editing and voting a post, *every review requires a minimum of two reviewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find details about suggested edits in the FAQ post: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)

It was always the case, that approval or rejection of a suggested edit requires two users. Two notable exceptions are:

- If you're reviewing an edit on your own post.
- If you choose "approve and edit" or "reject and edit". (This should not be misused, see older discussions here: [Abuse “Reject-and-Edit” to reject singlehandedly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29984) and [Rejected into a tiny edit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28597).)

This is a good thing - it is better if more than one user sees the proposed edit and

If you check your past reviews [on your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews), you can see that there were in many cases two reviewers. You can also use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1396914/suggested-edits-review-the-given-user?userid=293846) which shows only suggested edits. (On your profile page, you get all reviews. Keep in mind, that SEDE is only updated once a week.) Another place where you can see your past suggested edit is the [history in the review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) - where you can choose to display your own reviews.

To add some examples:

- [1560475](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1560475) is a suggested edit on your post, so you were able to approve it singlehandedly.
- [1548484](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1548484) is a suggested edit on a post by different user, there were two reviewers.

Comment: Hard to imagine that a long time I was always the second or third person to approve an edit, and now as a rule - the first one but there can be obviously no other explanation. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user at first you can only approve edits on your own posts. Thus at first it will always be a direct approval.

Comment: @quid I did not mean edits on my own posts. This has happened only once so far.

Comment: @user alright, but see https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1003567 you were first to review.and it took 15 minutes to get approved after that. Maybe you did not pay attention to it back then.

Comment: @quid I cannot tell you what was there three years ago. I can only admit that I possibly did not pay attention to the issue back then. I have no other explanation at the moment.